# Why is the Razor page unable to access a child List?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, json.net

I am writing an ASP.NET Razor/Blazor app that is retrieving a set of checklist templates from an MSSQL server.

The query returns the entire checklist template array structure in JSON format, which matches the class layout for the checklists.

Each checklist tamplate has an array of phases associated with it. The checklist classes are:

```cs
 public class ChecklistTemplate
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public List<ChecklistTemplatePhase> Phases { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChecklistTemplatePhase
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
        public Guid ChecklistTemplateId { get; set; }
        public int Ordering { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I am processing the returned result with

```cs
            // Get the JSON result in chunks
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                json_result += reader.GetString(0);
            }

            // List of all the checklist templates available
            List<ChecklistTemplate> checklist_templates_list;

            // Fill our list with the JSON returned from the SQL server
            checklist_templates_list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChecklistTemplate>>(json_result);

            // Testing accessing the phases list works
            foreach (ChecklistTemplatePhase p in checklist_templates_list[0].Phases)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", p.Name);
            }

            // Return our populated list
            return await Task.FromResult(checklist_templates_list);
```

This works perfectly. In debugging mode, the checklist_templates_list exactly matches the JSON structure returned from the MS SQL server.

I have a Razor component that calls this method on `OnInitializedAsync()`. Razor component is

```cs
@page "/ChecklistTemplates"
@using ChecklistApp.Data
@inject DataAccessService DaService

<h1>Checklist Templates</h1>

@if (checklist_templates_list == null)
{
    <div>No checklist Templates</div>
}
else
{
    foreach (ChecklistTemplate c in checklist_templates_list)
    {
        // This works
        @c.Name

        // This doesn't
        @c.Phases[0].Name
    }
}

@code {
    private List<ChecklistTemplate> checklist_templates_list;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        checklist_templates_list = await DaService.GetChecklistTemplates();
    }
}
```

I can display the properties of the `ChecklistTemplates` themselves, but when I access the `Phases` members in any way, I get

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> ChecklistApp.Data.ChecklistTemplate.Phases.get returned null.

Again, in debugging mode, checking the value of `checklist_templates_list` in the Razor component shows the whole tree, including the attached and populated `Phases` which would indicate to me that the deserialization is working properly and the class instance is available to the Razor component. But when I try to access the Phases list, I get the above error.

Why can I print members of the `Phases` child List in a normal C# method but not in the Razor component?

Comment: Are you positive that *every* item in `checklist_templates_list` has the `Phases` property initialized?

Comment: No, no I am not. I deleted the row with 0 Phases and the code started working. I discounted that possibility because I thought I was accessing the 0th template which _does_ have Phases. Perhaps the deserialization was changing the order.

Comment: @devNull Actually, I've just figured it out: The page was processing the 0th template then  moving onto the 1st template which has NULL Phases. This explains the behaviour I was getting when stepping through the code. It was throwing the exception on what I thought was the last Phase of the 0th template but was actually during processing of the NULL Phase of the 1st template. Can you please provide your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved?